# Android How to increase Battery level in text view

Tags: android

Hello every one I am developing an app in which I am getting battery level and displaying it in a textview. Now I want to increase this level 1% after each 5 sec and want to show this increment.
I have tried following code but i can't get my output

### java code

```
public class ChargingActivity extends Activity {
    TextView textBatteryLevel = null;
    int level;

    private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
            level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    // add your stuff here
                    level++;
                }
            }  
         , 5000);
            textBatteryLevel.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "%");
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chargingactivity);
        textBatteryLevel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btrylevel);
        this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

But Level of Battery is not increasing after each 5 sec. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to have "added your stuff" not where it tells you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using the `postDelayed(...)` method of the `View` class and also don't use an actual `BroadcastReceiver`.

For example, `Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` is a *STICKY* broadcast and as such doesn't need a `BroadcastReceiver` to handle it. Instead if we pass `null` as the first parameter to the `registerReceiver(...)` method, no receiver is actually registered but the return from that call is the `Intent` from the sticky broadcast. Example...

```
Intent batteryIntent = registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

The next step is to setup the 5 second update for the `TextView`. The Android `View` class has a `postDelayed(...)` method which accepts a `Runnable` parameter as well as a delay in milliseconds. Example...

```
textBatteryLevel.postDelayed(levelChecker, 5000);
```

The `postDelayed(...)` method of `View` is a one-shot (non-repeating) 'post' so make sure it is reset within the `run()` method of the `Runnable` each time it is called.

I haven't tested the following code but I think it should work. Bear in mind however, there's no guarantee that the level of battery charge will change within any 5 second period. It probably takes about 1 minute per 1% to charge my tablet and similar on my phone so I certainly wouldn't expect to see an update to the `TextView` every 5 seconds.

```
public class ChargingActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textBatteryLevel = null;
    int level;
    LevelChecker levelChecker = new LevelChecker();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chargingactivity);
        textBatteryLevel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btrylevel);

        // Get the current battery level
        Intent batteryIntent = registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        level = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);

        // Set the starting level
        textBatteryLevel.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "%");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        textBatteryLevel.postDelayed(levelChecker, 5000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        textBatteryLevel.removeCallbacks(levelChecker);
    }

    private class LevelChecker extends Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent batteryIntent = registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
            int currentLevel = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
            if (currentLevel != level) {
                level = currentLevel;
                textBatteryLevel.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "%");
            }
            textBatteryLevel.postDelayed(levelChecker, 5000);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move text changing code inside TimerTask.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
            level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    level++;
                     textBatteryLevel.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "%");
                    }
                }
            , 5000);
        }
      };
```

Comment: `level++;` should come after displaying the text.

Comment: Then provide a stack trace of exception in your question.

Comment: @Divers : The life of a `BroadcastReceiver` is from the call to `onReceive(...)` until that method exits. A `BroadcastReceiver` should *NEVER* perform any long-running action and creating a `Timer` in `onReceive(...)` is never going to work.

Comment: @Squonk So you think that TimerThread (which is used inside Timer) would be killed by system during execution? Is it possible?